# "Invalid pointer dequeued from free list", breakpoint in malloc_error_break not helping

Tags: c++, memory, sdl

I know the line of code causing the problem, but I don't know why. This is the error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x6080001416b0: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

and the relevant code:
(I'm making a kind of strange pet sim where you build dogs, to explain the weird dog stuff)

```
while (!quit)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
    {
        switch(e.type)
        {
            case (SDL_QUIT):
                quit = true;
            case (SDL_KEYDOWN):
            {
                Dogpart newDogpart(100,20);
                allDogparts.push_back(newDogpart); //the problem line
            }
        }
    }

    //game code
}
```

If I comment out this line:

```
allDogparts.push_back(newDogpart);
```

it doesn't crash when I trigger SDL_KEYDOWN.

allDogparts is a vector of a struct called Dogpart

```
std::vector<Dogpart> allDogparts; //declared globaly
```

I add a couple Dogpart's to allDogparts like this before the "while(!quit)" game loop starts, but these aren't problematic:

```
allDogparts.push_back(Dogpart(50,10));
```

I thought this might be a scope problem, but the new parts I add seem to remain  there when I step through the code. Stepping through, once SDL_KEYDOWN registers and the new part is added, I get all the way through the game loop and it crashes on this line for reasons I don't understand:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
```

Any help fixing this or even just explaining what's happening would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Dogpart:

```
struct Dogpart{
public:
Dogpart(float x, float y);
float x, y, w, h;
Uint8 r,g,b;
void update();
void render(SDL_Renderer* renderer);

bool mouseOver;
v2 mouseClickOffset; 

enum S_STATE
{
    DEFAULT,
    PRESSED, //clicked or touched down and held
    RELEASED //one frame, after pressed is false
} s_state;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to add a stack allocated variable to your vector?  Those go away when the function scope disappears.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but when I stepped through and it wasn't going away I assumed that wasn't the problem. Being somewhat new to working with c, I'm having a lot of trouble with memory. How would I go about adding variables to a vector while the main loop is running?

Comment: What's inside of that "dogpart"? Most likely you have pointers in it, and forget to add copy constructor. Also see, [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: @Dweeberly: It doesn't work like that. Stack variable will disappear, but the vector will retain its copy till the vector itself is destroyed.

Comment: Added 'Dogpart' definition to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac with Xcode, you may also use the "Enable Address Sanitizer".
In Xcode 7.3, select "Edit scheme" then the Run or the Test page, "Diagnostics" tab and check "Enable Address Sanitizer".

It provides memory corruption diagnostics similar to valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

you have trashed your heap. On linux run the program under valgrind, it will point out your errors. You can also try electric fence

If not linux please indicate your platform

Comment: @PeterSmyth http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html says it works on mac too. Or you could try `-fstack-protector-all` compiler flag (gcc or clang) - while it is weak there is a chance it will be enough to spot problem.